# navigating SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, rgdal, r-maptools, r-sp

This is probably a simple question but, I would like to view each output area on a map, having downloaded the boarders from [here](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/census/spatial/2011/index.html). Choosing the 2011 OA and getting the Full resolution, extent of the realm.

I have upzipped it...and read in the shp file using the following

```
require(maptools)
mm <- readShapePoly('OA_2011_EW_BFE_V2.shp')
```

How do I plot or view the coordinates for each output area?

Comment: if it was read in correctly. you should be able to do plot(mm). This will be a very simple map.

Comment: if the answer to your question is not `plot(mm)`, then please formulate your question more precisely.